# Is it informal to use "so on " in the article?

Tags: formal-language, informal-language, formality

I have written this phrase

> The input of the DNN is the features extracted automatically by feature_extractor model, which are given to the first hidden layer, and the outputs of this layer are given to the next layer and **"so on"**.

Is *so on* here informal? What should I use instead ?

Comment: You should say "I have written", not "I have write". Using and so on is fine and not informal. I hope those quote marks aren't in the text.

Comment: Also, since "the features" is a plural, the sentence reads better as "The inputs of (or to) the DNN are the features…" Your version "The input of the DNN is …" is not *wrong*, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**So on** is not super formal, but will be found in a lot of relatively formal writing. I would not avoid it without having some specific reason to expect that it would be rejected. I've seen it in legal judgements.

**So forth** is a little more formal, but basically means the same thing. You might use "**and likewise for each successive layer**. You can also make it more formal while keeping *so on* by adding "for each successive layer" or similar to that formulation.

Comment: In a science or math context, "and similarly..." would be more usual than "and likewise..."